# Deleting symlinks do not work every time using file:

Tags: ansible

I have a task that is supposed to remove files and symlinks.  It works as expected every time except for one specific symlink.  It's maddening!

In /etc/init.d/  I have some files and symlinks, examples:

```
file examples: 
/etc/init.d/ic-server
/etc/init.d/ic-broker
symlink examples:
ic-server.ampm1 -> /etc/init.d/ic-server
ic-server.ampm2 -> /etc/init.d/ic-server
ic-server.bgp1 -> /etc/init.d/ic-server
ic-server.esm1 -> /etc/init.d/ic-server
```

Here are my tasks:

```
  - name: delete init.d links and files pass 1 of 2
    file:
      path: "{{ item }}"
      state: absent
    with_fileglob:
    - "/etc/init.d/ic-server*"
    tags: deltest

  - name: delete init.d links and files pass 2 of 2
    file:
      path: "{{ item }}"
      state: absent
    with_items:
    - "/etc/init.d/ic-server"
    - "/etc/init.d/ic-broker"
    - "/etc/init.d/new_ic-server"
    - "/etc/init.d/ic-server_new"
    tags: deltest
```

The play runs without errors, but EVERY TIME, it skips deleting the ic-server.ampm2 symlink.  It deletes the ic-server.ampm1 symlink.
I cannot figure out why it's ignoring  ic-server.ampm2